# Support for Quickbooks enterprise with new quickbooks API V3

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I was previously using QBO/QBD API to connect to quickbooks enterprise, but it looks like these services have been deprecated.

The new QB API V3 seems to only work with quickbooks online.

For example, when I navigate to API explorer for my customer's enterprise data, I receive the message:

You're logged in with an account that does not have a QuickBooks Online subscription. Please try another account.

Do we continue to use the old API to access enterprise data?

Answer (score 0):

For QBD, you can use QBSDK. If you have a published app which uses V2 then it is recommended to make it use V3.
For QBO, you can always use V3 REST APIs.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Just to be clear--there is no REST API anymore that can be used for Enterprise (data accessed through Intuit Sync)?  We need to install an app on a machine?

Comment: yes. QBSDK for desktop application. WebConnector + QBSDK for Web

Comment: @ManasMukherjee I think this is an incorrect answer.. I think the opposite is true.  Can you provide references to verify?

Comment: IPP's FAQ pages are not update yet. But whatever I had mentioned in my post is correct. PFB Nimisha's post.